# Binary: Generating all possibilities in array

Tags: python, arrays

I have somewhat of a unique situation where I'm running into a roadblock. I'm looking for an eloquent solution to the goal, if someone is able to help with that.

Situation: An array of numbers (between 0 and 1) is provided. If the elements in the array are close enough to either 0 or 1 (0.25 in this example) they are rounded. I then would need to generate every possible binary array given the 'unknown' elements.

Example:

```
data = ([0.05,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1])
data[data < 0.25] = 0
data[data > 0.75] = 1

x=-1
for n in data:
    x+=1
    if ((n != 0) and (n!=1)):
        data[x] = 2   
data = data.astype(np.int)
```

This leaves me with array `[0 0 2 2 1 1 1]`
I then would like to get it to generate

```
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1]
[0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
[0 0 1 1 1 1 1]
```

I was thinking numpy array, but when I started doing:

```
x=-1
y=-1
data2 = data
while (2 in data):
    data = data2
    x+=1
    for n in data:
        for m in data[x,n]:
            if (m==2):
                data[x,n] = 0
```

It was giving me error of not being able to do the initial pass because it was a 1d array... I don't know. I'm sure there is a better solution than my while and for loops. Does anyone have any insight on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

data = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]

r = 2

combs = product([0, 1], repeat = r)
result = []

for c in combs:
  j = 0
  a = data[:]
  for i in range(len(data)):
    if data[i] == 2:
      a[i] = c[j]
      j += 1
  result.append(a)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

You can get `r` (the number of `2`'s in the array) by initializing it to zero and incrementing it every time you find a `2` in the array, in the loop you already have, also, you can minimize greatly the complexity of the nested loop above (`for i in range(len(data)):`) by using an array that stores the indices of `2`'s in the array.

Modification to the first loop:

```
r = 0
p = []

for i, n in enumerate(data):
    if (n != 0) and (n != 1):
        data[i] = 2
        r += 1
        p.append(i)
```

Modification to the second loop:

```
for c in combs:
  a = data[:]
  for j, i in enumerate(p):
    a[i] = c[j]
  result.append(a)
```